# where can i find the ipn settings for the paypal test environment

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, cs-cart

I need to set up PayPal to work with my shopping cart, and am currently using the test (rather than live) environment.

The test accounts are apparently meant to be set up through developer.paypal.com, but though I can change some of the account settings, I can't find out where I should be changing the following:-

"Your PayPal account should have the following settings:

```
Instant Payment Notification - off
Payment Data Transfer - off
Auto Return for Website Payments - off
Return URL - blank"
```

Where should I be looking for these? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you,

- Smychi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create the accounts through developer.paypal.com, yes, but once the account is created you would manage it through http://sandbox.paypal.com.  Login there with your sandbox seller account that you're using, then click into the profile and configure IPN the same way you would on a live account.

Comment: That's what I was looking for- it makes sense now, thank you. Yes- I was looking at the developer account (and interface) rather than the sandbox accounts the former is used to set up.